# Data migration from AzureStorage to SQL database

Tags: sql, .net, database, azure

I have two identical tables in different databases (Azure and SQL).

The first one contains data in it, the second one is empty.

What I need is the most elegant way to migrate data from one table to another.

As of now I am struggling to choose between code approach (write some tool which has the connection strings to both of databases and migrate data via some framework e.g. EF or dapper) and script (have no idea if it is possible, if so - I would like to get some advice what script language to use).

It also has to be testable for data is important.

Thanks!

Comment: When you say SQL database, do you perhaps mean MS SQL Server database? (SQL is a language, supported by many different dbms products.)

Comment: You mentioned "AzureStorage" in your title. Not sure I understand. Is your data in an Azure Storage table? Or are you using SQL Database service (with its storage in Azure)? Please edit your question to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

you can create [Linked Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/create-linked-servers-sql-server-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017), write stored procedure for data shipping and create schedule which executes implemented stored procedure.

Linked server can be used in this way:

```
 INSERT INTO LOCAL_TABLE
    SELECT * FROM [SRVR002\ACCTG].myRemoteDb.dbo.REMOTE_TABLE
```

Please note that: the implementation may vary based on the complexity of your need

Comment: If the OP is using SQL Database service, you cannot do this. And the way the question is written, it's unclear what the OP is actually using.

Answer (score 0):

If it is just once off, use the SQL import export wizard. It connects to both SQL on-prem and Azure. [See this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/overview-import-export?view=sql-server-2017).

For regular updates / synchronization, look to [Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/data-factory/).